# Is it possible use UINavigationController but hide its navigation bar (replace it with customized toolbar) and go back button

Tags: iphone

I hope to switch between 2 UIViewController using UINavigationController. (AUIViewController, BUIViewController relate to UIView AView,BView)

AView has an UIButton, BView has an UIButton also.
If I press the button on AView, it will push BViewController and display BView.
If I press the button on BView, BViewController will pop and go back AUIViewController.

I hope to use UINavigationController's navigation function but hide its 'go back' bar and navigation bar, only use 2 buttons to tell UINaviationController what it needs to do.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

to hide UINavigationController's navigation bar:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

To push a view controller from a button:

```
- (void)pushNextViewController {
    NextViewController *page = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:page animated:YES];
}
```

To pop a view controller back one:

```
- (void)popToLastViewController {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: worth noting, that another method: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; allows to show/hide the controller with animation.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide it in interface builder too:

- Select the nav controller object
- In the 4th tab on the right, under 'navigation controller', deselect 'shows navigation bar'