# UIView being cached?

Tags: ios, uiview

Ok this is a little hard to explain but here I go. On "`View1`" I use a `UIView` animation to go to "`View2`". The animation I do is a fade through black, switching views. I get to `View2` by doing `-addSubview`. Now lets say we are on `View2`, and my action gets called to go to `View3` using `presentModalView`. Since I need to remove the "`View2`" view, I do [`self.view removeFromSuperview`]; in my `viewDidDisappear` method so that the animation going to `View3` is not screwed up.
Here is the problem, when I go from my "`View3`" back to "`View1`" I use a `presentModalView` again with an animation flip. Now you know when you usually flip views, you see a background in the back of a color (usually white), instead it is my "`View2`". So it is like it is being cached in a way. 
Does anyone know why this is? If I need to post code, I can.

Comment: I think that Apple recommends using a separate view controller for each separate "screen". I know this isn't really an answer, but it may go more smoothly if you roll with the framework.

Comment: It is a separate view controller. I am adding a separate view controller (another xib), as a subview.

Comment: View controllers should be permitted to control their own views, I think—you may have more luck transitioning between view controllers rather than between views. It sounds to me like `UINavigationController is a good fit for this use case.

Comment: Now since my app is using absolutely no UINavigationControllers whatsoever, is there any easy tutorial converting it from plain UIViewControllers to UINavigationControllers while hiding the Navigationbar and toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually check this tutorial about using the `UINavigationController`:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/

To hide your Navigation Bar you can actually see this post:

[Is it possible use UINavigationController but hide its navigation bar (replace it with customized toolbar) and go back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489398/is-it-possible-use-uinavigationcontroller-but-hide-its-navigation-bar-replace-it)

Edit 1:

Uploaded the project now here: http://www.2shared.com/file/qU-QT8fl/Project.html
Read the ReadMe.text file. :P

Comment: Ok so I read it but let me get one thing right here, I do not have to do anything in IB to change a UIViewController to a UINavigationController correct? The only change is the switching views code and thats it?

Comment: You can do: Put an UIViewController inside your UINavigationController by XIB, or, you can add it in code. Basically after that you will need an reference to your UINavigationController (IBOutlet), so you can push and pop views from it.

Comment: Ok I am little confused. Are there any tutorials converting from my state to using to UINavigationControllers? I understand what you are saying but just not sure how to do it. I don't want to mess up my app. I already have like 8 XIBs in it and all are uiviewcontrollers.

Comment: Humm... I would need to check your project and tweak it a bit to implement the UINavigationController. I can't help you much more without actually seen it... Check my profile and send me an email, so we can get in touch.

Comment: I can't send over my current project, but if you want I can make a 2 XIB sample app with my current switching views code, and maybe you can tweak it to show me the differences? Is that ok?

Comment: Sure mate send it and I help you out.

Comment: I don't see an email on your profile but I uploaded  the sample project to megaupload. Heres the link: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=8FQE8NR0
If you can modify the code too to fit the same type of transitions that is already in there, that would just be superb!
Also I accepted your answer too :D

Comment: Just a reminder... The uinavigationcontroller handles the transitions between views...

Comment: Ok I will remember that, were you able to download the project?

Comment: I am answering you from cell phone. =P as soon as I get home I will make the changes and let you know.

Comment: Thanks! It really means a lot to me. I would love to share this too with others since it is a hot topic.

Comment: Wow you explained it very well! So just to be clear, my XIBs require no editing? I know the appDelegate needs some changes but thats easy.
So in the end, all I need to do to convert my app to using UINavigationControllers is:
1. Convert the code in the appDelegate
2. Change all of my switching views code to the ones like yours

Is that correct?

Also I really need my animations, so if you can, can you please show me how to do that? Also do you want my project modified with a 4.3 deployment target so that it works for you?

Comment: Humm if you need new animations you will have to drop the uiNavigationController idea. I can make a new Project so you can achieve that...

Comment: If you can make a new project that would be great! Would it also solve my problem of my UIViews being cached because in the end I want to achieve the same animations while still fixing this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: I will make a new project. Send me an email so we can get in touch to: sauron.is.alive@gmail.com (yes I am a Lord of the Rings geek...).